# Why does this code is not valid in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I started to learn Kotlin, I'm writing my first lines of code in this language.

I was surprised that this does not compile

```
fun sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: Array<Int>): Int {
    var sockets = HashMap<Int, Int>() 
    for (socket in ar)
    {
        if (sockets.containsKey(socket))
        {
            sockets[socket]++; // <= Error here "No set method providing array access"
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a [report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19249) saying that this is a compiler bug... but I'm surprised it existed unsolved for so long so I might be misunderstanding something.

I had to do

```
sockets[socket] = sockets[socket]!!.inc();
```

What it is horrible and super verbose.

I come from c# world and I do [XXX]++ all the time!! What's wrong with that in Kotlin?

Comment: Could it be because ‘sockets[socket]’ could be null? Then you must assign a value?

Comment: That's all the code, nothing hidden... I have no idea what that is not allowed

Comment: I understand that but sockets is a hashmap. And the value within ‘sockets[socket]’ is determined at run time. On compile time the compiler has no way to know if there a value or not. I the case there is no value presence i.e ‘sockets[socket] yields null. How would you increase the value of null by one? It is a valid compiler error. You will have to make sure an assignment like you did in tour work around.

Comment: You can change your if statement, extract the value maybe with an it operator? Increase its value by one and re-assign it. Or something like val s = sockets[socket] ; if (s!=null) { sockets[socket] = s+1 }. The if statement is kind of unwrapping the optional null value of s. Making sure it is an int which can be increased by 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `get` that `sockets[socket]` is, has a return type of `V?`; it can return null if there is no value in the map for `socket`. Even though you have the `if (sockets.containsKey(socket))` there the compiler does not know that (for instance, if `sockets` was shared, what's to stop another thread setting it to null after the `if`). So what happen when you call `++` on your null?

One alternative to your verbose one is:

```
sockets.merge(socket, 1, Int::plus)
```

Comment: Why is `HashMap` readonly? It implements `MutableMap`... I'm sorry if my question is too basic, I have just a few hours of kotlin development.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `Obj[XXX]++` idiom is not prohibited in Kotlin.
The problem here is that result of `sockets[socket]` call has nullable type (`Int?`) and postfix increment expression works only for non-nullable types (because under the hood it makes `.inc()` call).

Look at this hypothetical example:

```kotlin
class HashMapWithNonNullableGet<K, V> : HashMap<K, V>() {
    override fun get(key: K) : V = super.get(key)!!
}

fun sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: Array<Int>) {
    val sockets = HashMapWithNonNullableGet<Int, Int>()
    for (socket in ar) {
        if (sockets.containsKey(socket)) {
            sockets[socket]++ // sockets[socket] returns Int, so no errors here
        }
    }
    println(sockets)
}
```

In your case, it's better to refactor loop body to:

```
for (socket in ar) {
    sockets.computeIfPresent(socket) { _, v -> v + 1 }
}
```